# Cannot scroll when 'OnMouseWheel' event in delphi's mdi parent form

Tags: delphi, scroll, mousewheel, mdi

I have the MDI form with MDI child forms.

As you know, MDI from create scrollbar when child form is beyond the area  automatically.

I'd like to use this scrollbar when i do mouse wheel.

Comment: The title of your question indicates something isn't working, but the body of your question is asking how to implement something, and the two are barely related. Please [edit] your question to be a bit more clear.

Comment: Seeing as there's no response, I'm voting to close this question as unclear what you're asking. It seems you started asking one question, but then ended up asking a different question. The question you started asking is the right one, which hints you are having trouble with `OnMouseWheel`, but then you never actually said what the issue is with it. Instead you asked how to do something.